# Sliver Animation with disappearing and shrinking items flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

What is the best way to achieve this type of animation where the top logo and bottom icons disappear and only the middle text shrinks and stays visible. I know that Slivers are used but I don't understand how?

The Example:

[image]

Comment: Try using this package draggable_home: ^1.0.3. https://pub.dev/packages/draggable_home

Comment: Can you include what you;ve tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Use custom ScrollView  with silver app; bar no need a package for it

```
   class CustomScrollApp extends StatelessWidget {
        const CustomScrollApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

   @override
        Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
    body: CustomScrollView(
    slivers: [
     const SliverAppBar(
      backgroundColor: Colors.red,
      pinned: true,
      expandedHeight: 200,
      title: Text('CustomScrollView'),
      flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
          background: Image(
        image: NetworkImage(
          'https://picsum.photos/250?image=9',
        ),
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
      )),
    ),
    const SliverToBoxAdapter(
      child: Text(
          'lorem ipsumlorem lorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem '),
    ),
    SliverList(delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
      (context, index) {
        return ListTile(title: Text('Item $index'));
      },
    )),
  ],
));
}
}
```

Comment: Here is only one text widget, is there any way to add the image and the icons? You don't need to add them, just add another two Text widgets that can appear and disappear like in the image above

Comment: you can add any widget instead of Text Widget , plz try your self